# Minimal $x_n$ such that $\frac{a+x_n}{b+x_n}$ are all distinct, where $a,b=1,\dots,n,$ and $a\ne b$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisibility

What is the smallest $x_n$ such that all $\frac{a+x_n}{b+x_n}$ fractions are distinct, where $a,b=1,\dots,n,$ and $a\ne b$?

WLOG, due to symmetry, we can assume $a\lt b$ (or $b\gt a$) instead of $a\ne b$ condition.

For example, $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ because $\gcd(1,2,3)=1$.

But if $n=4$, then $x_n=0$ doesn't work because $2/4$ simplifies to $1/2$.

The sequence $(x_n)$ starts as $0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 10, 12, 12, 21, 21, 25, 32, \dots$ and is not in OEIS.

It appears $x_n\sim O(n^2)$, from computing first $100$ terms.

Can we characterize $x_n$?

One interesting property to investigate would seem to be, when does $x_n = x_{n+1} = \dots = x_{n+k}$ and is there largest such $k$?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You know, there are intolerant persons everywhere. This site isn't an exception alas. Don't bother. You have a well written question, you have worked on it, you will surely get answers.

Comment: Isn't your issue connectable to "visibility problems" (from the point of view of an observer situated at the origin of $[0,N] \times [0,N]$ as described [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html) ? Your quotients would be considered as slopes of line segments connecting the origin to points $(b+x_n,a+x_n)$

Comment: @JeanMarie If I'm reading that correctly, it seems we are actually looking to have all points $(a+x_n,b+x_n),$ $a,b=1,\dots,n$ visible from origin in a lattice where points $(a',b'),a'\le x_n, b'\le x_n$ are removed and no longer blocking the view.

Comment: Good formulation. Is it effective for solving your issue, I don't know...